# SwiftUi - hide "Back" button and navigation bar (appears for a fraction of second)

Tags: swiftui, navigationbar, swiftui-navigationlink, navigationlink

I'm using this code to hide a navigation bar and Back button but when the view is loaded i still can see the back button for a fraction of second and then it disappears. Is there any way to prevent it from being shown?

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        NavigationLink(destination: DeferView { WeekView(journey: self.launcher.completeJourney!) }, isActive: self.$launcher.readyJourney ) { EmptyView () }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .navigationBarTitle("")
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the same modifiers also for link destination,

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        NavigationLink(destination: DeferView { WeekView(journey: self.launcher.completeJourney!) }
                                    .navigationBarHidden(true)   // here !!
                                    .navigationBarTitle("")      // here !!

              , isActive: self.$launcher.readyJourney ) { EmptyView () }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .navigationBarTitle("")
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me do you have any other suggestion?

My code:

struct FirstSwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
      VStack {
        Text("First SwiftUi View")
        NavigationLink {
          SecondSwiftUIView()
        } label: {
          Text("Next View")
        }
      }
      .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
      .navigationBarTitle("")
    }
}