# Remove `UIMenu` from `navigationBar.backBarButtonItem`

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, ios14

With ios14, apple introduced the UIMenus we know to the navigation bar, so we could go back a couple of screens within a single long tap.

[image]

However, I want to remove that behavior from my app.

I tried doing a new class without setting the menu to the UIBarButtonItem and later on adding it to the navigation bar like shown below.

```
class BackBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {
  @available(iOS 14.0, *)
  override var menu: UIMenu? {
    set {
      /* Don't set the menu here */
      /* super.menu = menu */
    }
    get {
      /* return nil doesn't work either */
      return super.menu
    }
  }
}
```

```
let backButton = BackBarButtonItem(title: "BACK", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton
```

Doesn't work ^^^

`navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.menu = nil   // still displays the menu`

This didn't seem to work either.

How could I remove that menu?

Comment: Why would you want to remove it?

Comment: We are a fintech, and we need the users to follow a very specific path because of some banks regulations

Comment: navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItems(nil, animated: true) works ?
 or you can put a new one set nil again , can you try ?

Comment: Someone else's asking the same thing https://stackoverflow.com/a/63964382/14351818 and https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/653913 but it looks like it's not working for you

Comment: @aheze yes, I tried everything they and a bit more in the second link you sent me. I'll keep trying

Comment: @sekoya nope, didn't work :/