# Set global default back button display mode for all UIViewController instances

Tags: ios, swift, back-button, ios14, back-button-control

iOS 14 introduced **configurable Back button mode**.
Eg. you can have "Back" label text on the button, but in the compact history menu you can still see the proper title of previous controllers.

I'm looking for a easy, pleasant way to configure the default mode, so all UIViewController instances during runtime will have default mode set, like `UINavigationItemBackButtonDisplayModeGeneric`

I wonder if there is a way to do that without subclassing UIViewController or remember to always configure manually every instance of UIViewController
(via `viewController.navigationItem.backButtonDisplayMode = UINavigationItemBackButtonDisplayModeGeneric`).

Any handy method which does not require extensive refactoring of hundreds of UIViewController instances greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Without subclassing I think is not possible since `navigationItem` requires an instance to work with and can't be modified directly from extensions

```
class GenericViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // your code here  
    viewController.navigationItem.backButtonDisplayMode = UINavigationItemBackButtonDisplayModeGeneric
  }
}
```

And use that where ever you need

```
class viewController: GenericViewController
```

This is a really good approach since you have control over what implements it and what's not considering that it might not be there in all scenes

Answer (score 0):

To solve the same problem, I used the swizzling technique

```
import UIKit

private let swizzling: (UIViewController.Type, Selector, Selector) -> Void = { forClass, originalSelector, swizzledSelector in
    if let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(forClass, originalSelector), let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(forClass, swizzledSelector) {
        let didAddMethod = class_addMethod(forClass, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod))
        if didAddMethod {
            class_replaceMethod(forClass, swizzledSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod))
        } else {
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
        }
    }
}

extension UIViewController {
    
    static func swizzle() {
        let originalSelector1 = #selector(viewDidLoad)
        let swizzledSelector1 = #selector(swizzled_viewDidLoad)
        swizzling(UIViewController.self, originalSelector1, swizzledSelector1)
    }
    
    @objc open func swizzled_viewDidLoad() {
        if let _ = navigationController {
            if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
                navigationItem.backButtonDisplayMode = .generic
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
                navigationItem.backButtonTitle = "Back"
            }
        }
        swizzled_viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

And in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` call

```
UIViewController.swizzle()
```