# Disable Long Press back Button (callout menu)

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, uinavigationbar, ios14

iOS14 introduced that long-press on back button which opens a callout menu to go back to specific VC in stack.

I would like to disable it, is there a possibility to do such a thing, and if yes how ?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Try to set `backButtonDisplayMode` to `.minimal` on your VC ->

```
if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
    navigationItem.backButtonDisplayMode = .minimal
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/3656350-backbuttondisplaymode

Comment: I upvoted but it actually doesn't work

Comment: To elaborate on @charleyatwork's answer, if you have ended up with a blank menu because you were setting `title` or `backButtonTitle` to an empty string to have just the chevron icon, you can use this snippet but in an `else` block continue to set `backButtonTitle = ""` to get the best of both worlds.

Comment: Yes, this works beautifully in iOS14, to replace the previous "hack" of setting the `backButtonTitle`.

Comment: Neither setting the `backButtonTitle` nor setting the `backButtonDisplayMode` actually works to suppress the menu.