# SwiftUI - disable NavigationView back button menu

Tags: swiftui, menu, back-button, navigationview

So, I have the following code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink("Page", destination: PageView())
                .font(Font.system(.largeTitle))
        }
    }
}

struct PageView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
    }
}
```

When the "Page" NavigationLink is selected, you are redirected to a new screen (PageView). When you long-press (hold) the back button to go back to the main screen (ContentView), a menu appears (new feature in iOS14+):

[image]

Is there a way to disable the menu popup on a long-press gesture, **using SwiftUI (without adding custom back button)**?

Cheers everyone, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a workaround. Not pretty, but it works ^^.

First I was trying to use [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) library to change the underlying `UIKit` components since there is a [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63964382/8700044) to your problem for `UIKit`. But it didn't turn out well.

So here comes the workaround.

#### Idea

Overlay the back button with an invisible view that has the same tap gesture, but no long press for the menu.

#### Solution

Finding out and reaching the exact position of the back button independent of user device type.

[image]
[image]

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var showPageView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink("Page", destination: PageView(), isActive: $showPageView)
                .font(Font.system(.largeTitle))
        }
        .overlay(NavigationBackButtonHiddenTouchView(isActive: $showPageView))
    }
}

struct PageView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
    }
}

struct NavigationBackButtonHiddenTouchView: View {
    
    @Binding var isActive: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Color.black.opacity(0.0000001).frame(width: 80, height: 35)
                    .onTapGesture { isActive = false }
                
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(height: navBarHeight)
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    
    var navBarHeight: CGFloat = {
        return UINavigationController().navigationBar.frame.size.height
    }()
}
```

#### Problem

Making it reusable for further navigation links (you need to handle it manually, ugly but possible)

You might also have to handle hiding `NavigationBackButtonHiddenTouchView` from your parent view, if it causes complications.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! That's a solution. Nice job. The only problem is, that you don't have a click indication on the button. I have cleaned the code a bit:

```
struct BackButtonMenuDisabled: ViewModifier {
private enum Constants {
    static let overlayOpacity = 0.01
    static let backButtonWidth: CGFloat = 50
}

@Binding private var isActive: Bool

init(isActive: Binding<Bool>) {
    self._isActive = isActive
}

private var navigationBarHeight: CGFloat {
    UINavigationController().navigationBar.frame.size.height
}

func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content.overlay(
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Color.black.opacity(Constants.overlayOpacity)
                    .frame(width: Constants.backButtonWidth, height: navigationBarHeight)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        isActive = false
                    }
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Hm, I see. You could make a custom animation for the `tintColor` of the bar button item. But it would be challenging to access it.