# .NET MAUI Long Press Issue

Tags: maui, maui-ios

Is there a way to disable the .NET MAUI long press navigation option on IOS? This is causing navigation issues throughout our app.
[Long Press Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prCgH.png)

I tried to find documentation regarding this but I haven't found anything regarding this functionality.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue, however, it seems the back button menu cannot be disabled, as long as the navigation bar shows its native back button, the menu is available. See https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/653913, you can raise an issue on Github:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues.

Comment: Not sure if you are using shell or not but there are relevant iOS answers that you can port you need to create a custom native navigation and replace your new version of the back button with the existing one you have  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63964382/7462031, you will have to use Renderers/Handlers and override these