Remove default "Back button in SwiftUI
New to coding.....
Trying to remove the default "Back" button in the upper left-hand corner of SwiftUI screen view.
Have tried every suggestion found in research with nothing helping to remove it.
The most common response is: .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true), but I either don't know how to use it (Very possible), or it doesn't work.
Any help would be massively appreciated.
import SwiftUI
I have tried many suggested options with no favorable results.

I have answered the same question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62158125/swiftui-hide-back-button-and-navigation-bar-appears-for-a-fraction-of-secon/78285292#78285292. Please try the solution and let me know.
